# How to iterate on different lists according to a parameter

Tags: bash

I have a script that can get a list of folders or get them automatically with `find`. I'd like to write a single loop that handles both cases: if there are parameters, use them, otherwise, create the list automatically.

So far, I have something like:

```
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
then
    for value in "$@"
    do
        v1=$(process_data "$value")
        <do things with $v1>
    done
else
    for value in "$(find ...)"
    do
        v1=$(process_data "$value")
        <do things with $v1>
    done
fi
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
then
    data="$@"
else
    data="$(find ...)"
fi

for value in "${data[@]}"
do
    v1=$(process_data "$value")
    <do things with $v1>
done
```

but this `data` assignment can be potentially big. In a language with pointers this should not be a problem, but in `bash` it doesn't look good.

Is there a better way to achieve my needs?

Comment: Sadly, Bash's indirection syntax `${!var}` doesn't work with array variables, or I'd recommend that.

Comment: Not directly, but `foo=(1 2 3); t=foo[@]; for x in "${!t}"; do ...; done` will iterate over the contents of the array.

Comment: Also, consider that `find foo.txt` will output `foo.txt` if that file exists. You may be able to do something like `find "$@"` so that your code works with `for value in $(find ...)` in either case; it's just a matter of providing the appropriate arguments in each case. (Read [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to iterate over the output of a command, though.)

Comment: @chepner, probably I can make some `find "$@"` adaptation, but it will do the potentially lengthy find. Not a good idea.

Comment: Why not? How many more arguments do you pass to `find`? If your script can handle receiving `n` arguments, then `find` can probably handle `n + k` arguments (assuming `n + k` doesn't exceed your OS limit on command-line size).

Comment: The problem are not the arguments, but having to wait for minutes for `find` to find what we already have as an input parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These don't look right:

> ```
> data="$@"
> data="$(find ...)"
> ```

If you want `data` to be an array, you need

```
data=("$@")
data=($(find ...))
```

---

What you can do is assign to the positional parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" = 0 ]
then
    # no arguments; default to all matching files
    set -- $(find ...)
fi

for value in "$@"
do
    # things
done
```

This does mean that the loop can't start until the `find` command finishes.  To solve that, an alternative might be to turn it around and make using `"$@"` more like the output of `find`, i.e. stream it to a pipe, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

args_or_find() {
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
    then
        printf '%s\n' "$@"
    else
        find ...
    fi
}

while read -r value
do
    # things
done < <(args_or_find)
```

The natural extension to improve robustness using `\0` instead of `\n` as separator is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a script like this to have processing loop only once:

```
if (($#)); then           # arguments are passed
    arr=("$@")
else                      # build array from find command's result
    arr=()
    while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
        arr+=("$f")
    done < <(find . -name '*.txt' -print0)
fi

# main processing loop
for line in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "processing... <$line>"
done
```

Comment: But that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid, the generation of that extra intermediate array.

Comment: Sorry it is not clear from question that you're avoiding an intermediate array. Please keep in mind that out of both answers posted, this is the only safe solution that will work with all kind of filenames that may contain spaces, newlines or glob characters (use of `-print0` option)

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. That was what I tried to say when I said "this data assignment can be potentially big", which also implied that the `find` could also be long. I'm already aware that spaces can be a problem and I was planning to implement the code with `-print0`, `printf "%s\0"` and `read -d''`. Thanks for the warnings!